# Get image size from traced torchscript model

Tags: c++, torch, yolo, torchscript

When exporting a yolo5-model to torchscript (using yolo5's [`export.py`](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/export.py)), the input image size has to be fixed using the [`--imgsz`](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/export.py#L617)-argument.

**How can I access this value (the expected image size) later using torch's C++-API?**

I know that the information is there: the exported model is a zip-archive in disguise and, after unzipping, the size appears in `extra/config.txt`.
So I could theoretically use a zip-library to retrieve this information.
However, it feels hacky and might be unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the files in the `extra/` directory in the zip archive using an overload of the `torch::jit::load` method:

```cpp
torch::jit::ExtraFilesMap extra_files{{"config.txt", ""}};
m_module = torch::jit::load("path/to/model.torchscript", gpu_id, extra_files);
std::cout << extra_files.at("config.txt") << std::endl;
```

Will yield the content of `config.txt`, which contains JSON, i.a. the required shape of the input image.

It should be easy to troll the desired value from that string.

Note that this solution only works if the `config.txt` file has been added to the zip archive explicitly.
[`yolov5`'s export.py does that](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/915bbf2/export.py#L124).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a c++ expert but this code works for me. I saved two `double` variables on python and was able to read them in c++. I tried to `memcpy` straight from the `string` but I wasn't able to, that's why I created this sequence of char.

```cpp
torch::jit::script::Module module;
torch::jit::ExtraFilesMap extra_files{{"var1", ""}, {"var2", ""}};

module = torch::jit::load("model.pt", device, extra_files);

std::string var1_str = extra_files.at("var1");
std::string var2_str = extra_files.at("var2");

double var1;
char b[] = {var1_str[0], var1_str[1], var1_str[2], var1_str[3], var1_str[4], var1_str[5], var1_str[6], var1_str[7]};
memcpy(&var1, &b, sizeof(var1));

printf("Var1 read: %.17g\n", var1);
```

This is the **python** code I used to save the variables:

```cpp
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, sample)

extra_files = {'var1': np.array(var1).tobytes(), 'var2': np.array(var2).tobytes()}

traced_script_module.save('model.pt', _extra_files=extra_files)
```

This was based on @pasbi answer.

Comment: Yeah looks like you have used 8 chars to assemble a double. Should work, however, I wouldn't call it readable. For very little data, I like yolo's approach to serialize to JSON: flexible and simple.